# Mac: Selenium Error, Permission Error and selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

The error is

```
/Users/erwinmac1/PycharmProjects/MachineLearning/venv/bin/python /Users/erwinmac1/PycharmProjects/MachineLearning/main.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/erwinmac1/PycharmProjects/MachineLearning/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/common/service.py", line 72, in start
    self.process = subprocess.Popen(cmd, env=self.env,
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/subprocess.py", line 854, in __init__
    self._execute_child(args, executable, preexec_fn, close_fds,
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/subprocess.py", line 1702, in _execute_child
    raise child_exception_type(errno_num, err_msg, err_filename)
PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/Users/erwinmac1/Desktop/Chrome zip'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/erwinmac1/PycharmProjects/MachineLearning/main.py", line 6, in <module>
    driver = webdriver.Chrome(PATH)
  File "/Users/erwinmac1/PycharmProjects/MachineLearning/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/chrome/webdriver.py", line 73, in __init__
    self.service.start()
  File "/Users/erwinmac1/PycharmProjects/MachineLearning/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/common/service.py", line 86, in start
    raise WebDriverException(
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: 'Chrome zip' executable may have wrong permissions. Please see https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/chromedriver/home
```

While my code is

```py
from selenium import webdriver

PATH = "/Users/erwinmac1/Desktop/Chrome zip"
driver = webdriver.Chrome(PATH)

driver.get("https://www.youtube.com")
```

I don't know why this shows an error I've re-installed it a couple of times and it still shows this error any helps??

Comment: Welcome to SO.  Is the ```PATH``` the path of a zip file?  If so, shouldn't it be the path of the actual chromedriver binary?

Comment: You want the path to the chromedriver.exe instead of zip.

Answer (score 1):

Your path is invalid (PATH = "/Users/erwinmac1/Desktop/Chrome zip")

go to your desktop and edit name of chromedriver as chromedriver and refresh project and rerun